# Vue.js Documentation Example Not working in Codepen?

Tags: html, vue.js, codepen

I'm just trying to replicate an example for checkboxes from [Vue.js's documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html), but when I import Vue into codepen.io and then paste the code for multiple checkboxes into the JS field, then the HTML into the HTML field, I get

```
Checked names: {{ checkedNames }}
```

and when I click the checkboxes for a specific name, like "Jack", this doesn't change anything. It still reads.

```
Checked names: {{ checkedNames }}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It's working in vue beacause the internally have vue-setup on their website and to use it in codepen you have to import vue cdn and then you need to create a vue instance and append in a root DOM. You can refer below code snippet.

The below code is of vue 2.0 and vue now has latest version vue 3.0 you can check that out as well [Vue 3](https://v3.vuejs.org/)

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checkedNames: []
  }
})
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="checkbox" id="jack" value="Jack" v-model="checkedNames">
    <label for="jack">Jack</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="john" value="John" v-model="checkedNames">
    <label for="john">John</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="mike" value="Mike" v-model="checkedNames">
    <label for="mike">Mike</label>
    <br>
    <span>Checked names: {{ checkedNames }}</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried copying this exactly and just get a blank result. Also, I've made sure to import the Vue 2.x package into the JS field first. **Edit:** Removing the import line seems to fix that. Why is that the case?

Comment: It's working for me, sharing my codpen link please check https://codepen.io/mondal10/pen/gOLByVR

Comment: I have imported vue here in stackoverflow snippet to show demo in the stackoverflow itself, but when you copy pasted the code from here to codepen which already had vue imported might have raised a conflict.